Math formatting in text editor.
Just noticed that there is no shortcut in the text-editor to start-stop MathJax environment.
I personally didn't need it but some users might not see the tips on the right; hence it could be useful to have it next to the "code" shortcut.

http://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons may be useful for you, but I haven't added quant.SE support.
